# R replacing zeros in dataframe with next non zero value

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe with a column containing zero values:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(a, b)
df
```

How can I replace the zero values with the last non zero value ie column df$b to be:

```
 1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way with `na.locf` from `zoo`.  Although this method does change some values to `NA` in the process, the code is nice and painless.

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(with(df, ifelse(b == 0, NA_real_, b)), fromLast = TRUE)
# [1]  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1
```

An alternative to this, and one that might be faster than `ifelse` on long vectors, is

```
na.locf(with(df, { is.na(b) <- b == 0; b }), fromLast = TRUE)
# [1]  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1
```

Comment: And another variation: `na.locf(with(df, replace(b,b==0,NA)), fromLast = TRUE)`